# ActiveRecord Json Should fail no?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, model

I am using the [ActiveRecord Json Validator Gem](https://github.com/mirego/activerecord_json_validator) and I have the following object thats trying to be saved to the model, which should fail, but instead isnt:

```
[1] pry(#<Api::Internal::V1::UsersController>)> backup
=> #<UserBackup:0x24eddeed
 id: nil,
 location_name: "test",
 user_params: {"user"=>{"user_name"=>"GeorgeLucas", "email"=>"asdsadasdas", "auth_token"=>"jesus"}, "controller"=>"api/internal/v1/users", "action"=>"create"}>
[2] pry(#<Api::Internal::V1::UsersController>)> backup.save!
=> true
```

As you can see theres a unsaved `UserBackup` model object in `[1]` and in `[2]` is saves, the json in `[1]` is missing somethig that is set to required: `first_name`.

The model looks like such:

```
class UserBackup < ActiveRecord::Base
  PROFILE_JSON_SCHEMA = Rails.root.join('config', 'schemas', 'user.json_schema').to_s

  validates :location_name, :presence => true
  validates :user_params, :presence => true, json: {schema: PROFILE_JSON_SCHEMA}
end
```

The Json Schema Looks like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "first_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "last_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": false
        },
        "user_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "format": "email"
        },
        "auth_token": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

According to my schema, `first_name` must be a string and it is a required field.

In my json being saved, its missing entirely. Which means that the model should not save the object to the database.

## Update One:

Looking at the model object the `user_params` doesn't look like a json object at all, it looks like a hash of hashes. So with that in mind, here is the controller:

```
module Api
  module Internal
    module V1
      class UsersController < BaseController
        before_action :restrict_api_access

        def create
          params_json = params.to_json
          backup = UserBackup.new(location_name: from_site, user_params: params_json)
          binding.pry
          if backup.save
            return render json: {}, status: 200
          else
            return render json: {}, status: 422
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

`params_json` is indeed a json object:

```
[3] pry(#<Api::Internal::V1::UsersController>)> params_json
=> "{\"user\":{\"user_name\":\"GeorgeLucas\",\"email\":\"asdsadasdas\",\"auth_token\":\"jesus\"},\"controller\":\"api/internal/v1/users\",\"action\":\"create\"}"
```

So I am unsure at this point, what exactly is going on.